# How to use a router to replicate a shape but smaller?

Tags: router, router-bit

I have a router template with a shape that I want to replicate on a piece of wood (it's some sort of oval) but it is a bit larger than I want it. I've never used a rabbet router bit but it seems that I could use one to replicate the shape while making it *bigger*, right?. Now, if the size of the bearing was bigger than the size of the cutting part of the bit, it seems that it would make a whole with a similar shape but smaller. Does such router bit exist? if yes, how is it called?

Or is there a better solution for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: How much do you want to reduce by, the template being "a bit larger" doesn't tell us quite enough ;-) If it's the kind of size reduction I'm thinking would the simplest option of a brass bushing do what you want? Fixed offsets from an edge (straight or curved) is precisely what bushings are for.

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be easier that trying to tweak existing tools to scale the work.

My first inclination would be to make a copy of the existing template on paper. Then you can use almost any multi-function printer to make a copy, but reduce it by some percentage. In a related manner, I suspect there is software you can use that will reduce a scanned PDF to a new size, which gets you the same result. (I've never used such software, though, and sizing real-world images with software is a bit of a black art.)

Alternatively, you can use a tool like a pantograph to help you free-hand a new template drawing, just at a reduced size.

Now, with your template drawing that matches the original, only reduced in all dimensions, you can fashion the new template as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

Graphus mentions using a bushing in his comment on the OP. If you rout around the *inside* of the template, then a bushing will work to make your newly produced part smaller. If you rout around the *outside* of the template then a bushing will only serve to make the new piece *larger*.

If you have an "outside" template, you could use the router to create a new, "inside" template which will, by it's very nature, be larger than the original template. (Use the smallest diameter straight-cutting bit you can find to make this new template to minimize the enlargement.) Then find a large enough bushing to use your new, "inside" template to make the final piece of work the size you're after.

If you need a significant reduction such that you cannot find a large enough bushing to make the reduction in one pass, you could make a series of "inside" then "outside" templates, making each one smaller than before. When you're done, you'll have gone through a lot of plywood/hardboard/etc, but you'll have a nice set of templates that should work for just about any size you'd need in the future!